# Read last Inserted row in Sql according to its Time stamp

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, identity

sql has a Table called emp.

```
emp(emp_id int IDENTITY primary key, EmployeeName varchar(50),.......)
```

I want to Insert a record to above table. Here is my code in asp.net.

```
DBconnection dbcon = new DBconnection();
string query = "insert into emp values('" + TextBox_EmpName.Text + "','" + ....);
int no1 = dbcon.insertQuery(query);
```

I have another table called emp-relation

```
 emp-relation(emp_id int primary key, count int, ....) 
     -- foreign key (emp_id)references emp(emp_id)
```

My problem is when I inserting the emp row ,I dont know what is the `emp_id` since it created by auto. And when I am going to insert to emp-relation , I want to get `emp-id` since it is the foreign key.

How can I do this? Is there any way to read last Insert row in Sql according to Time stamp or some thing? I believe that records are not sorted according to inserted timestamp in nature. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's bascally two ways.  The first way is to return the new ID from the first insert query:

```
insert into emp values(...)
select scope_identity() as NewID
```

The second way is to lookup the first row when you insert into the relation table:

```
insert  emp-relation
        (emp_idm, ...) 
select  emp_id
,       ...
from    emp
where   emp_name = @EmpName
```

You have to pass in enough columns to make the reference unique.

Comment: Thank you Andomar. Your Second way: If there is more than one record using same EmpName. This is not going to work rit? Can you explain bit about your first way please.

Comment: Right, the `where` clause has to return only one row, so if EmpName is not unqiue you'll need more rows.  `scope_identity()` returns the last inserted `identity` value.  You could read it back in client code and use it in the 2nd query.